# Shifting from apache/mod_wsgi to nginx/uwsgi

Tags: php, django, nginx, apache2, mod-wsgi

Till now i have been using `Apache` `mod_wsgi` for deploying Django apps and `Apache2` for PHP apps.

Now i always try to use things which are used in major companies. i ahve read they use `ngix/uwsgi`

Now i want to shift it to `nginx/uwsgi`

Now does that mean that i have to remove `apache` and nginx will serve the purpose of `apache`

and my `php` apps can also run in `nginx` and i don't need `apache` at all

i had beein using `mod_macro` to create `virtualhosts` is all that stuff still possible in `nginx`